# Búsqueda por fecha de inicio o por fecha de fin

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo este filtro que me esta buscando por `fecha inicio`/`fecha fin`, pero ahora necesito hacer que si me ingresan solo la `fecha inicio` busque por la **fecha inicio menos 3 meses** nada más o por **fecha fin menos 3 meses** nada más.

Tomando en cuenta que ya poseo un query ¿se podrá hacer localmente? ¿o usando el query sin tener que modificarlo?

```javascript
$("#aplicar_filtro").click(function filtrar_colapse() {
      var fecha_i = String($('#fecha_inicio').val().replace(/-/g, "")); //aqui estamos reemplazando los guiones (-) q trae la separacion de fecha por espacios en blanco o vacios
      var fecha_f = String($('#fecha_fin').val().replace(/-/g, "")) //aqui estamos reemplazando los guiones (-) q trae la separacion de fecha por espacios en blanco o vacios
      var fecha_i_ = unix_date_ccr_pcr(parseInt(new Date($('#fecha_inicio').val()).getTime() + 14400000))
      var fecha_f_ = unix_date_ccr_pcr(parseInt(new Date($('#fecha_fin').val()).getTime() + 82800000))
      var fecha_limite = adaptar_fecha((new Date()).getTime() + 86400000)
      var fecha_i_i = ((new Date($('#fecha_inicio').val())).getTime() + 14400000)
      var fecha_f_f = ((new Date($('#fecha_fin').val())).getTime() + 82800000)
      var fecha_limite = adaptar_fecha((new Date()).getTime() + 86400000)
      var rango = fecha_f_f - fecha_i_i

      if ((fecha_i_i > fecha_f_f) || (fecha_i_i > fecha_limite) || (fecha_f_f > fecha_limite)) {
        des_reportes_error('RANGO DE FECHAS INVÁLIDO Y/O FECHA MÁXIMA EXCEDIDA')
      }
      if ((rango > 31622400000))
        des_reportes_error('RANGO MÁXIMO EXCEDIDO')
    }

    if ((fecha_i_i <= fecha_limite) && (fecha_f_f <= fecha_limite) && (fecha_i_i <= fecha_f_f) && (rango <= 1646415166)) {
      $.ajax({
            url: "Solicitud_Ctr/lista_report",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "json",
            error: function(jqXHR) {
              var error = error_ajax(jqXHR);
            },
```

Comment: Tienes un error en el javascript, donde pones una llave de cierre `}` después de `'RANGO MÁXIMO EXCEDIDO')` pero que no se corresponde con nada, pues en el `if` anterior no abres la llave  y debe estar dándote problemas de ejecución seguramente.  Tampoco has puesto el javascript completo.